# what is meaning $ A(O_K)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading the paper " The number of extensions of a number field with fixed degree and bounded discriminant." by Jordan S. Ellenberg and Akshay Venkatesh(https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309153.pdf). In the second section pg no 726 they define $ A=Spec(R)$ Later use some notation $A(O_K)$. need some help with understanding notation.

Comment: It seems like scheme-theoretic notation. You can see it as the scheme morphisms $Spec(O_K) \rightarrow A$, or, better, as the morphisms of $O_K$-algebras $A \rightarrow O_K$.

Comment: @Mindlack you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, I am posting my comment as an answer:

It seems like scheme-theoretic notation. You can see it as the scheme morphisms $Spec(O_K)→A$, or, better, as the morphisms of $O_K$-algebras $R \rightarrow O_K$.

Comment: You mean $R\to O_K$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Mindlack I do not  understand  how is $R$ is $Q_K$ algebra